# Basic high school physics problem regarding the formula speed is the distance over time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, distance

> A train 1 moves from a point $A$ in straight line at $38 km / h$ and after $2.5$ hours is followed by a train 2 which moves from the same point $A$ in straight line at $80$ km per hour. At which time the train 2 is going to reach the train 1? And at which distance from the original point $A$ the train 2 is going to reach train 1?

I formulate the time where train 2 reach train 1 as $t_{A}=t_{B} +2.5 h$ and I know that $S_{A}= d_{A} / t_{A}$ and $S_{B}= d_{B} / t_{B}$ but I dont know how to formulate my second question or how to proceed to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would suggest you not to use$t_A$, $t_B$, $d_A$, $d_B$, etc., for the two trains because they're named $train_1$ and $train_2$ respectively.

Now coming to the question, I don't think you can find the time $t_2$ all at once. You'll have to substitute that formula you've found for time $t_2$ in the formula for distance. So, first find the distance $d$  with the time $t_2$ and speed $S_2$ at of $train_2$. Similarly, find the distance $d$ with $S_1$ and $t_1=t_2+2.5$(the equation you had found) of $train_1$. That will be the distance $d$ of the trains from the original point $A$. Put an '=' inbetween them and evaluate.

**Note:** They're at the same place when they meet that's why I took both of their distance as $d$.

Comment: Thanks! Just not sure how to formulate the time :/. What is correct? timetrain1=trimetrain2 +2.5 hours or timetrain2=trimetrain1 +2.5 hours? Or neither of those? @lee

Comment: @Cos, $t_1 = t_2 + 2.5h$ is correct

Comment: @Cos, you'll have to use this equation- $t_1=t_2+2.5$ in the equation to find distance. I don't think you can find time all at once.

Comment: Think I got it; I use the equation $t_{1}=t_{2}+ 2.5$, I state the problem of finding where but trains meet as solving $d_{1}=s_{1}t_{1}=s_{2}t_{2}=d_{2}$ and haveing the speeds used $t_{1}=t_{2}+ 2.5$ in that equation to find $t_{2}=2.26$, then sum 2.5 to get $t_{1}$. So I get the distance where but trains meet, i.e $d_{1}=d_{2}$ and times. What do u think? @lee

Comment: Yeah @Cos, that's it! And I've edited my answer too....

Comment: Im trying antoher one, its an emergency helping the daughter of a friend. Hope dont get stuck with it :/ @lee

Comment: Can u help me with this one?https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/607539/computing-the-distance-where-two-solids-reach-each-other-using-basic-speed-formu  @lee

Answer (score 0):

If you make a graph with `distance from A` on the vertical axis and `time` on the horizontal axis, you will find that you have a straight line for each of the trains, and the slope of each line corresponds to the speed of the train.  I expect you can work out the equations of those lines, and solve them simultaneously (i.e. find the value of `time` at the point where the straight lines meet).